# ASP.NET CORE 3 frombody NULL with Bootstrap Table plugins

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-3.0, bootstrap-table

I'm trying to do based on this example in the bootstrap table
[query params](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#options/query-params.html#view-source). But the parameter I received always NULL, even I already set it before calling backend. I expect the value received should be **Supplier**. Thanks

**view**

```
<table id="supplier-inbox-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped text-center bootstrap-table"
   data-toggle="table"
   data-query-params="InboxTableParams"
   data-url="/AppService/Get_InboxTableData"
   data-method="post"
   data-pagination="true"
   data-side-pagination="server">
<thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th data-checkbox="true"></th>
        <th data-field="ID" data-sortable="true">ID No</th>
        <th data-field="Customer" data-sortable="true">Customer</th>
        <th data-field="StoreCode" data-sortable="true">Store Code</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

```
<script>
function InboxTableParams(params) {
  params.UserType = 'Supplier';

  return params;
}
</script>
```

**controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public string Get_InboxTableData([FromBody] InboxTableData inboxData)
{
  return inboxData.UserType;
}
```

**model**

```
public class InboxTableData
{
    public string UserType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where is data in your table or input field?

Comment: For now I don't want to display data. I just want to pass parameter from view to the controller. Even with data, my table display correctly, except when pass custom parameter such as UserType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call Get_InboxTableData,you will have three parameters,`UserType,offset and limit`.So you can try to use

```
public class InboxTableData
    {
        public string UserType { get; set; }
        public int limit { get; set; }
        public int offset { get; set; }

    }
```

result:
[image]